# How to get records based on one column in sqlite3 in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i am using sqlite in android application. there is one table with some columns .
ex:-

columns :- Id  name  url watched

watched has boolean values . When i query it returns a Cursor, in the Cursor i want all the records where "watched = false " to be shown first , followed by the records where "watched = true ".

How can i achieve this

Comment: This can help you: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `ORDER BY` so you can do something like this:
`SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY WATCHED` then to switch it from `true` or `false` ordered first you can use `DESC` or `ASC`at the end. Your statement would be:
`SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY WATCHED ASC`

`DESC` keyword means descending so in your case it would show `true` first
`ASC` keyword means ascending which would show `false` first